# sql server default procedure permissions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, create-table

I want to know what are the default permissions for sql server stored procedures.
For example, I created a user in database but no role or no permissions granted except execute permission like:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO [newUser]
```

later on me (as a **sa** login) created a stored procedure that makes just a select from a table like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.selectX AS
BEGIN
 SELECT ID, NAME FROM MyTable
END
```

and my user [**newUser**] can execute and see the result of select statement like:

```
EXEC dbo.selectX
```

up until now, I can assume that stored procedures have default permissions that my user don't have.
I tried other dmls like **UPDATE**, **INSERT**, **DELETE** and user managed to execute procedures successfully.
But! when I created a proceure with ddl as create table .. such as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.crtNT AS
BEGIN

    CREATE TABLE del(id int) --for test
END
```

and when the newUser executes this procedure error occurs like:

```
CREATE TABLE permission denied in database 'MyDb'
```

And here is my question: **By default, do stored procedures have permission with DML(select, insert, update vs.) but not with DDL(create, drop table vs.)**? Because I didn't see any explanation about this situation in Books Online or anywhere else.
Any comments will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that DDL statements are treated differently.

The procedures with DML statements work through the mechanism of [Ownership Chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) however as this quote from the [`EXECUTE AS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178106%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) documentation states

> Remember that ownership chaining applies only to DML statements.

Comment: since create table requires schema level permission, your explanation and the provided links are quite satisfactory.